# Как побороть JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

Tags: java, javafx

Пишет при выполнении кода:

> Error: Main method not found in class _Mixa01.MyClass, please define the main method as:
>      public static void main(String[] args)
>   or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

Что это и как исправить?

Answer (score 6):

@Andrew Bystrov написал верно, хотя, возможно, непонятно)

Как должен выглядеть файл `MyClass.java`:

```
package _Mixa01;

import javafx.application.Application;

public class MyClass extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // Здесь пишешь код
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Что бы не было таких проблем, создавай сразу JavaFX проект в своей IDE.

Answer (score 5):

Свой класс `_Mixa01.MyClass` наследуй от класса `javafx.application.Application`. Имплементируй метод `start(Stage stage)` и в методе `public static void main(String ... args)` напиши `launch(args)`. Всю остальную логику пиши в методе `start`

Answer (score 0):

это значит, что класс `_Mixa01.MyClass` не имеет метода
`main(String args[])`, который требуется для запуска класса как
программы. Он нужен без разницы, наследует ли ваш класс `javafx.application.Application`.

Answer (score 0):

Tоже столкнулась с такой проблемой, но простого решения нигде не увидела.
В моём случае оказалось всё очень банально - невнимательность.

В коде было несколько классов, в одном из них вообще не было метода, в другом `main` был указан и при запуске падала такая же ошибка:

> ... please define the main method as: public static void main(String[] args) or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

Проблема оказалась в том, что название .java файла у меня совпадало с классом без метода / с методом не main. То есть, переименованием файла в соответствии с классом, который содержит метод main, решило проблему.

Answer (score 0):

У меня эта ошибка возникла из-за того, что класс Main был создан вторым и IDE его в упор не видит. Создал новый проект, создал сперва Main, затем другой свой класс, скопировал код, ошибка исчезла.